# SMTP server fails to communicate with exchange server

Tags: java, sockets, email, smtp, exchange-server

I am in the process of writing an smtp server and while testing, I found that communications from an email client account that is hosted by an exchange server, the handling of the SMTP protocol fails.
I have a ServerSocket that I use to accept incoming connection requests:

```
ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(25);
Socket socket = sSocket.accept();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
     InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true)) {
    writer.println("220 example.mailserver.com ESMTP Postfix");
    String command = reader.readLine();
    handle(command);
}
```

The SMTP protocol is simple, after establishing the connection, the server initiates the conversation with a greeting and then reads from the input stream. The client server that is trying to send an email will then typically send the HELO or EHLO command.

In the case of an exchange server, the read simply times out.

I have tried to use an InputStream instead of the BufferedReader and handle the end of line myself. I have also tried to explicitly write '\r\n" instead of using println("220 example...");
I have even tried catching the SocketTimeoutException and write an addition \r\n and repeat the greeting but to no avail.

Does anybody know what the sending exchange server might be waiting for?
Is it expecting another command first instead of the greeting that I am sending?

I have thought about character encoding issues but then I guess I would still be reading character but interpreting them the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

After having read through the RFC0821 again where it explicitly says that every command is ended by a CRLF (\r\n), I no longer used PrintWriter#println(String) but instead print(String) and then an addition print("\r\n").
However, because I am now no longer doing println, I am loosing the auto flush capability of the PrintWriter that only comes into effect at println. So I added another PrintWriter#flush and that worked.